# How to split letters, letters with bracket and numbers in R?

Tags: r, regex

For example, I have a string `A1[5]B1C6`

I would like to split it into:

```
letter <- c(A, [5]B, C)     
number <- c(1, 1, 6)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `str_extract_all` from the `stringr` package, you can look, in the case of numbers, for numbers `\\d+` not preceded by a `[` `(?<!\\[)`:

```
library(stringr)
num = unlist(str_extract_all(x,"(?<!\\[)\\d+"))
[1] "1" "1" "6"
```

In the case of letters, that can be preceded by a letter or number in between brackets, you can do:

```
let = unlist(str_extract_all(x,"(\\[[[:alnum:]]+\\])*[a-zA-Z]+"))
[1] "A"    "[5]B" "C"
```

Comment: Very nice.. I was trying to get this.

Comment: @Sagar Thank you